# What is the correct translation for "licensed file"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

I want to know what would be a correct translation for a "`licensed file`", as in "*Requesting a download for a licensed file*" I just don't know what is correct:

> - Archivo licenciado
> - Archivo con licencia
> - Archivo bajo licencia

What is the correct translation?

Thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to see what a licensed file means in your case, but in any case I would say any of the three answers you suggested are right.

They sound right to me anyway, although I would personally use "archivo con licencia".

Comment: +1 I would also prefer "archivo con licencia"

Comment: Thank you, I'm using this translation right now and I think is the best to my context. Have a nice day !

Comment: I would also say "archivo con licencia".